# Get Directions Between 2 CLLocation's

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 `CLLocations` that I want to give directions between. What could I use to give the user directions between a saved location and their current location? The saved location is saved when the user presses a button and the current location is where they currently are.

Comment: if you're targeting iOS7, have a look at `MKDirections`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirections_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKDirectionsHandler

Comment: there is also the MTDirectionsKit - it can ask google/bing/mapquest or whatever! + it can draw it onto a map

Comment: there is an open API of _MapQuest_ as well, which you can use as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code.

```
NSString* url = @"https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=40.815376,-73.045105&daddr=41.0,-73.045105";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

In Above URL you need to set first source address (Latitude and Longitude) and second destination address (Latitude and Longitude).